# Linux: how can I determine if an application is doing sequential or random disk I/O?

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, io

Everyone knows that databases tend to do lots of small random I/O while big data things like Kafka tend to do large sequential I/O, but if I'm approaching this as a sysadmin without making assumptions, how do I determine what a running application is doing on my system, or in general whether my system is seeing? Without knowing how the application is written, how do I determine whether it is doing mostly *sequential* or *random* I/O, thereby making it easier for me to choose the right kind of disks, etc, to deploy?

I can use `iostat` to get the average request size (avgrq-rz) of each IOP and a count of the number of IOPS (r/s + w/s). How do I determine whether these are mostly *sequential* or *random*?

Comment: I've scoured the internet but haven't found any way to do this. Probably need to develop a SystemTap script to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there're actually couple of tools you can use to monitor this. Such as the one you mentioned, iotop and the iostat command.

Depending on your distribution, you can use either of the following to install iotop:

**$ sudo apt-get install iotop** or

**$ yum install iotop**

Run: root@tomcat-1-vm:/# iotop (to see list of disk I/O processess that are running)

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                  
24576 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
24580 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
    5 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H]
    6 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/u2:0]
    7 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
    8 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_bh]
    9 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
   10 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [lru-add-drain]
   11 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/0]
   12 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/0]
   13 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kdevtmpfs]
   14 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [netns]
   15 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [khungtaskd]
```

You may also display I/O activity just by passing the o phrase

Example: 
root@tomcat-1-vm:/# iotop -o

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :      11.91 K/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:      11.91 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                            
  835 be/4 tomcat8     0.00 B/s    7.94 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -Djava.util.logging.config.fi~he.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
 1371 be/4 tomcat8     0.00 B/s    3.97 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -Djava.util.logging.config.fi~he.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

To learn more about disk i/o ouput and information you can check the [proc filesystem page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Again depending on the distribution, you may install iostat as follows:

**$ sudo apt-get install sysstat** or

**$ yum install sysstat**

Run: root@tomcat-1-vm:/# iostat -dx 5

```
Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 (tomcat-1-vm)       05/29/2018      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.22    0.01    0.31     0.31     3.67    24.34     0.00   12.56    8.50   12.73   4.04   0.13

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.40    0.00    0.40     0.00     3.21    16.00     0.01   18.00    0.00   18.00  18.00   0.72

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00   25.30     0.00  5546.18   438.41     4.38  173.17    0.00  173.17   3.14   7.95

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     2.81    0.00    0.40     0.00    12.83    64.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     1.20    0.00    4.21     0.00    21.64    10.29     0.03    7.24    0.00    7.24   0.38   0.16
```

You may also refer to the following [iostat examples post](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/iostat.htm#examples) on options you can include for more report.

Another command to use is the dstat.

Example: 
root@tomcat-1-vm:/# sudo apt-get install dstat

```
root@tomcat-1-vm:/# dstat -tdD total,sda,sdb,sdc,md1 60 
----system---- -dsk/total----dsk/sda--
     time     | read  writ: read  writ
29-05 23:58:15| 318B 3797B: 318B 3797B
29-05 23:59:15|   0   473k:   0   473k
29-05
```

Comment: But how does this tell me whether the i/o is _sequential_ or _random_?